# Looking for an extremely simple AJAX script

Tags: ajax

I need a very basic, simple and lightweight AJAX script.

Does anyone have a shell of such a script they can share?

Here's what I have:

- I have a PHP script on the server that echo's the current date and time on the server
- I just need the javascript that calls the php script and loads the echoed text string into a js var so I can use it in my app

(the reason I need the server's clock is that all visitors to the site have to work off the same clock. The app does not work for visitors outside the server's timezone.)

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I guess I should note, and not sure if it matters, that other aspects of my app are using the Google jQuery API --> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: Not sure if jQuery 1.4.4 is an issue, so I updated my api call to the latest 1.6.0 version.

Comment: I ended up taking a different path to solving my issue --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953493/pre-process-javascript-before-downloading-to-client-machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JQuery is perhaps the right answer for AJAX but you can also do this in plain old Javascript as follows:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadXMLDoc(){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            //the callback function to be callled when AJAX request comes back
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }       
            xmlhttp.open("POST","<<url of web address>>",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Aater...I am going to give this a try. Looks just like what I was asking for!

Comment: No problem Dr. DOT. You can also look at this tutorial if you need to understand this code better. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: This method also is on conflict with Google jQuery API in the IE8 browser --> Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Tue, 10 May 2011 16:08:15 UTC


Message: Access is denied.

Line: 138
Char: 355
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1):

You can find a simple example here:

```
AjaxCall = function(Data, WebServiceURL, Callback) {
    var request;
    var url = WebServiceURL;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    Callback(request);
                } else {
                    alert("Sorry, an error occurred. " + request.responseText);
                }
            }
        };
        request.open("POST", url, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send(Data);
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        url += "?" + Data;
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        if (request) {
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState === 4) {
                    if (request.status === 200) {
                        Callback(request);
                    } else {
                        alert("Sorry, an error occurred. " + request.responseText);
                    }
                }
            };
            request.open("GET", url, true);
            request.send();
        }
    }
};
```

The the ajax functionality in jQuery is great but does mean a greater page download for one simple Javascript function.

You can find a downloadable fully worked example on my blog here:

> http://www.willporter.co.uk/blog/simple-ajax-script.aspx

It uses ASP.NET on the server side but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has made very simple ajax methods for you to use. You can find more information about them [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Sample:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/SomeUrl/On/The/Server',
     data: { SomeValue: 10 },
     success: function(data, status)
     {
         // On Success
     },
     error: function(data, status)
     {
        // On Error
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Tejs. But jQuery does not work in my app. Been at this for 3 days now trying to troubleshoot. The jQuery is in conflict with GoogleAPI Jquery. Plus the jquery option does not work in ie8. I decided that if I can just get the simplist aja call to the server to capture the text string then I would have what I need. I'll paste my error below

Comment: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 141"  data: no]

Comment: Have you tried simply using `jQuery` instead of `$` for the symbol? There should be no problem using jQuery on a site unless the symbol is in conflict.

Comment: Just type `jQuery` instead of `$`. `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`.

Comment: Continues to not work in IE8 --> Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Tue, 10 May 2011 15:58:03 UTC


Message: Access is denied.

Line: 138
Char: 355
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Look into this maybe : http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/01/simple-ajax-function-example/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a more reliable library overall, but the lightest-weight AJAX methods I have found are the extremely simple [Feather AJAX](http://celtickane.com/labs/feather-ajax/), coming in at **1.6 KB** (with room for compression), or a [one-liner snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6943) that I can't guarantee.

The risk of extremely lightweight libraries is that if they break, you're relying on the owner to fix it instead of a team of developers.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to solving your problem is to based your times on UTC instead of server-local time.  You can even show the client local times based on that utc time, with a little work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion "uosef". Actually, my current app is way too mature (in terms of its development). The piece I am adding with the callback to server is an add-on. Scaling back to UTC timezone codes would require me to rip apart my whole app, which I am not keen on tackling.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest [AJAX Generator](http://drax.biz/project/ajax-generator)?
I am developer, and it is commercial tool but it has demo as well.

What you could do with that tool is:

- put annotation on your PHP function
- run AJAX Generator on PHP source file
- include generated JavaScript file in HTML page and use PHP service as if you were calling function

To make it more clear, here is example code:

```
//example.php
<?php
//@WebService
function getServerDate(){
    return date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
}
?>
```

Now run generator on: **example.php**

Output would be two files: **example_service.php** and **example_caller.js**

Now you need to:

- add example_service.php in same directory where is example.php and
- include example_caller.js in index.html

[image: HTML code]

*Sorry for posting image instead of HTML code, but it wasn't showing properly.*