# Pre-Process Javascript before downloading to client machine

Tags: php, javascript

I want to pre-process a javascript file before downloading it the client browser. I have done this successfully with a css file, but when I apply the same criteria to my javascript file it does not work.

Does anyone know how to use PHP to pre-process a .js file before download?

Thanks

Comment: How do you mean "preprocess"? Minify it?

Comment: No. What I want to do is create a javascript var with the server's date and time stamp. So I want PHP to insert the current server datetime in a var before all web docs get put together for download to client browser. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file, let's say `jsfile.js.php`:

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
include('jsfile.js');
ob_flush();
```

Now instead of including .js file, just include this .php file.

**Small edit (after I saw your comment):**
If is only about added variables, you can define them in html, just before including the js file:

```
var timestamp = "<?php echo time(); ?>
<script src="jsfile.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, clever. Didn't think of doing it that way. I used .htaccess to "AddType application/x-httpd-php .js" and then I stuck a "<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript"); ?>" as line 1 in my .JS -- I'll give this a try and post back

Comment: CSS and JS doesn't need to have the correct extension. So you can use whatever suits you.

Comment: "lonut" thanks for the brilliant, yet simple solution. I have been spinning my wheels for 3 days trying to get jQuery to work along with a variety of other methods. Your hint made me develop such a simple solution -- and in only 5 minutes. Appreciate it!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

This project is great to minify, join and set variables in JS (but apparently discontinued for now): https://code.google.com/p/jspp/