# How to fetch a line (or whole file) from the server into a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm trying to avoid a much more complicated environment (such as JSP) to basically just get a few bits of basic information from the server environment into an otherwise static HTML environment. Those bits of information are, in effect, just what the youngest version of something is. There are only two such somethings, and, in any event, a low number N of them even if the site expands the idea into other areas. So, database access and such things would be WAY overkill - at least at this point in time.

My concept is to use JavaScript to both fetch the data and then place the data where it's needed on any given page. Doing this as the page is first formed is fine - it doesn't have to be asynchronous. The ONLY part I'm a little unclear on is how to fetch the contents of a file found on the same server into a JavaScript variable.

Any pointers appreciated.

As an aside, I took a cursory look into AJAX and found it to be WAY over-kill, but maybe I've just found sites that aren't good at describing it in basic terms. For example; I have no idea why I'd need any xml for my applications - seems REALLY silly! ... However, I'd like to at some point consider moving toward a Postgres database access strategy, but a persistent database connection would be needed, etc... My only purpose in mentioning these future goals is that if there's a path I should consider, sooner is always better!

Comment: Are the files you need to check in the web-folder (same folder, or subfolder, as the js-file)? If not, forget about doing it with only JS, that won't be possible. AJAX is your best bet, and why you would need XML, I've no idea. Usually, AJAX is done with simple echoing of values, or returning an JSON-object to the javascript-call. If you have PHP on the server, that would probably be the smart way, creating and ajax-call to the php-file on the server, have the php return what you need, and use that information in the callback of the ajax-call.

Comment: ajax can be as simple as $.get plus some parameters. Its is simple and widely used. its the way to go

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Presuming I don't use embedded JS, yes, they could be in the same directory on the server, but it would be nice if they could be in a different directory on the same server. As for Ajax, how about a pointer to a SIMPLE setup / implementation description page? All the ones I've seen get lost in the weeds and are written by people who've lost sight of the "competent beginner" and assume WAY too much - I can skip over beginner stuff I don't need! Also, can AJAX do persistent DB connections? ... Maybe create an "answer" instead of just a comment?

Comment: @Bindrid If you can point me at a web page that can describe such a "simple" solution, that'd be great. So far I haven't found one on my own! As I just mentioned to junkfoodjunkie, most presume WAY too much. ...I'm not a beginner by any means, but I'm completely ignorant about Ajax. Something that shared neither too much nor too little would be VERY welcome!

Comment: How about you just take a look at this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952353/looking-for-an-extremely-simple-ajax-script

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie WOW, that worked! :-) ... I'm no expert in JavaScript, but that was not just JavaScript but also involved Ajax? ... I guess I have to dig a bit more into it to see where the boundaries are! THANKS! ...And if you'd replied as an Answer, I could tag it as correct and helped your "reputation!" :-)

Comment: It's fine, it wasn't really my answer to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that follow...

...I want to point out that given my problem to solve (and how I think about it vs this other problem someone else solved) I would never have found this other solution that junkfoodjunkie pointed me to. It's the accepted answer another stackoverflow question, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952353/looking-for-an-extremely-simple-ajax-script). ...And it's because I'd have never found it otherwise that I'm leaving these breadcrumbs here...

What's interesting is that while the answer to THAT question purports to be about fetching XML, it actually will fetch whatever the contents are of the file you point it at! ... I haven't looked into boundary conditions of that - like binary files, and such - but for plain text contained in any ole file, it worked like a charm!